# $\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} k\lfloor\frac{n}{k} \rfloor = 1 + \sum_{k = 1}^n \sigma_1(n)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, ceiling-and-floor-functions, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions

For any $f: \Bbb{N} \to \Bbb{Z}$ there exists a unique transformed function $F:\Bbb{N} \to \Bbb{Z}$ such that:

$$
f(n) = \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}F_k\lfloor\frac{n}{k}\rfloor
$$

For example, set $F_1 = f(1)$.  Then at $n = 2$ we want to have $F_1\cdot n + F_2\lfloor\frac{n}{1}\rfloor = f(2)$, so we let $F_2 := f(2) - \sum_{k=1}^2 \lfloor\frac{2}{k} \rfloor$, similarly set $F_n := f(n) - \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \lfloor\frac{n}{k} \rfloor$.  Clearly the coefficeints $F_n$ are uniquely determined.

---

Knowing that, how can we prove that, if $T(f) := F$ in the above, $T(\text{A160664}(n))(n) = \text{id}$?

https://oeis.org/A160664

That is:

$$
\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} k\lfloor\frac{n}{k} \rfloor = 1 + \sum_{k = 1}^n \sigma_1(n)
$$

Comment: Look up [Möbius inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_inversion_formula#Generalizations)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, the $1$ on the right is spurious, as you can easily verify from $n=1$ (LHS = 1) or $n=2$ (LHS = 4).  Unless you somehow have defined $\sigma_1(1) := 0$?

The terms on the left are identically zero when $k > n$, so the LHS is equal to $$\sum_{k=1}^n k \lfloor \frac{n}{k} \rfloor = \sum_{k=1}^n k \sum_{d=1}^n \mathbf 1_{dk\le n} = \sum_{k=1}^n k \sum_{d=1}^n \sum_{r=1}^n \mathbf 1_{dk=r},$$ where $\mathbf 1_{P}$ is the indicator function that takes the value $1$ if the proposition $P$ is true and $0$ otherwise.

Now switch the order of the sums to get
$$\sum_{r=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^n k \sum_{d=1}^n \mathbf 1_{dk = r} = \sum_{r=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^n k \cdot \mathbf 1_{k \mid r} = \sum_{r=1}^n \sum_{k : k \mid r} k = \sum_{r=1}^n \sigma_1(r).$$